# SQLite nvarchar(100) field can accept 200 char field. Why?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a field defined as nvarchar(100).

I just noticed if inserted a new record (an 200 string value for example) the query works and not throws any exception.

Is a SQLite 'feature'?

Usign SQLite 1.0.94 with Visual Studio 2010 / C# and SQLite v3 dabatabse.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has a single unlimited TEXT datatype. See the documentation:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite doesn't recognize the limit you specified in statement, so it's not enforced.

In order to enforce it, you might need a statement like this:

`CREATE TABLE t (f TEXT CHECK(LENGTH(f)<101));`

So text with more than 100 characters cannot be inserted.